# Scoring Questionnaire Respondents using formula

Tags: r, plyr

A questionnaire with several single-choice questions was built to score respondents. Choices of each question were initially scored. This initial score may change but is irrelevant for the question. The `value` column presented bellow reflects this initial score.

I'd like to **score respondents** using a formula that weight questions. Since the formula may change to reflect different evaluation criteria, a more general way to score answers would be the natural choice.

**Simple example**

```
structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
.Label = c("Ind_1", "Ind_2"), class = "factor"),
question = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L),
.Label = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5"), class = "factor"),
value = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L)),
.Names = c("id", "question", "value"),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

**Representing this:**

```
id  question    value
Ind_1   Q1  1
Ind_1   Q2  1
Ind_1   Q3  3
Ind_1   Q4  2
Ind_1   Q5  5
Ind_2   Q1  1
Ind_2   Q2  2
Ind_2   Q3  3
Ind_2   Q4  2
Ind_2   Q5  4
```

**Formula:**
This is the formula to apply in order to score respondents

```
2*((Q1+ 1.5*Q2)/2) + 2.5*((Q3+(2*Q4)+Q5)/3)
```

**Expected Outcome**

```
id  scored_value
Ind_1   12.50
Ind_2   13.17
```

Hope this is clear enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be better answers. First, I converted that data from from long to wide using the `reshape2` package. Then I computed the scored value using the `plyr` package.

```
foo <- read.table(text="id  question    value
Ind_1   Q1  1
Ind_1   Q2  1
Ind_1   Q3  3
Ind_1   Q4  2
Ind_1   Q5  5
Ind_2   Q1  1
Ind_2   Q2  2
Ind_2   Q3  3
Ind_2   Q4  2
Ind_2   Q5  4", header=TRUE)

library(reshape2)
# convert from long to wide
bar <- dcast(foo, id ~ question)

library(plyr)
# for each id, compute the scored value
baz <- ddply(bar, .(id), summarise, scored_value=2*((Q1+ 1.5*Q2)/2) + 2.5*((Q3+(2*Q4)+Q5)/3))
```

Comment: thanks this is working as expected. I failed to think using the cast my molten formatted table.